# Number of lattice points $7$ units away

Tags: geometry, integer-lattices

A lattice point is a point in space which has all coordinates as integers. How many $3D$ lattice points are exactly $7$ units from the origin?

I'm thinking the answer to this is $3$, since we have only $(7, 0, 0), (0, 7, 0)$, and $(0, 0, 7)$. Is this correct? Feels too simple, so I think I might be missing something.

Comment: For completeness, "*are 7 units from the origin*" according to euclidean distance metric?  Or according to some other metric?  This should be clarified because the answer will depend on that.  For instance, in the [taxicab metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxicab_geometry) you would have $(6,1,0)$ and $(5,2,0)$ and $(5,1,1)$ etc... are all "distance" 7 away from the origin as well.

Comment: Don't forget negatives!

Comment: @JMoravitz: Don't be such a pedant! Without further clarification, distance means Euclidean distance.

Comment: @TonyK Many questions give not enough context. I suppose it cannot hurt to say a word here. So no need to be harsh...

Comment: @dietrich: I would say it is JMoravitz who is being harsh here.

Comment: @JMoravitz Yea, I meant eucledian distance, so if for point (x, y, z), the distance is root(x^2 + y^2 + z^2)

Answer (score 1):

The integral point $(x,y,z)$ has Euclidean distance $7$ from $(0,0,0)$ if and only if
$$
x^2+y^2+z^2=7^2.
$$
For $x=1$, the equation $y^2+z^2=48$ has no integer solution, and also for $x=5$ there is no solution. This follows from Fermat's theorem about the sum of two squares. For $x=0,2,3,6,7$ there are solutions. An example is $(x,y,z)=(2,3,6)$. This yields eight different possibilities $(\pm 2,\pm 3,\pm 6)$.
It is easy to list all solutions now. The total number is $54$, see [OEIS](http://oeis.org/A016725), which counts the number of different integral solution of
$$
x^2+y^2+z^2=n^2
$$
for $n\ge 1$.

Comment: So should I approach such a problem using casework when x = 0, 1, 2, .., n (for distance n from the origin)?

Comment: No, in general you can use Jacobi theta functions (see the references at OEIS above). From which course is this homework?